# TSQL rollup -return not null

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using Rollup clause and you how it shows aggregation at various levels `WITH NULL` values showing different levels of `rollups` e.g. `rollup(year,month,week)` would show subtotals at each level.

I want it rolled up and yet want to see only highest elvel of aggregation.
so I dont want to see any `null` values.

Any idea how can I do that?

Regards
Manjot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by "only highest level of aggragation?

You can avoid the NULLs by checking if a column in grouped, like so:

```
SELECT        CASE WHEN Grouping(GroupID) = 1 THEN '#ALL' ELSE GroupID END AS         GroupID,          
              CASE WHEN Grouping(SubGroupID) = 1 THEN '#ALL' ELSE SubGroupID END AS SubGroupID, 
              Sum(Value)
FROM          Table
GROUP BY      GroupID,
              SubGroupID
WITH ROLLUP
```

It will display #ALL insteaed of NULL.

Comment: @#$% YA! up vote on that one! nice solution! I was using ISNULL but then I was running into problems with when the actual value should have been null! THANKS!

Comment: My issue was with the value column returning null...I used Sum(ISNULL(Value,0)) to correct the issue.